# Looking for a temperature probe connector

Tags: connector

I have a temperature probe I need to connect to a PCB in a housing and I am looking for a good connector that require my needs.

The temperature probe has 3 wires of 26 AWG (0.1288 mm²).

Ideally I need something like a surface mount terminal block connector in which I don't need to physically join the wires. The connector ideally should have a height smaller then 5.00 mm due to the casing. It should be RoHS compliant and not too expensive (less than €1).

Can I possibly just use a crimp connection or will this affect the signal quality of the probe?

I have looked on all the big electronic component sites (Mouser, Farnell, Molex, ...) but with no luck so far.

Comment: Whether a connection will or will not affect the signal quality depends partly on what kind of a sensor it is. A DS1820-based digital thing probably wouldn't care as much as a Pt100 sensor.

Comment: It is going to be a Pt100 so are there extra things I should consider choosing this connector ?

Answer (score 1):

For a Pt100 in 2-wire or 3-wire configuration, connector resistance directly affects accuracy (specifically variation between contacts in connector resistance in the 3-wire case).

Screw terminal blocks are commonly used, eg, 5mm or 5.08mm pitch. SMT is not really a good idea for something that invites an idiot with a screwdriver to torque on it, unless  you like field failures. Use through-hole parts, would be my recommendation.